# Visual Studio 2010 text editor buggy caret

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I've had VS 2010 installed for about a year, and it's been running fine up until around a month ago.

Ever more frequently, and for no immediately deducible reason, the text editor starts moving the caret to weird places when I type "::", ".", "->", and the like.

I've done a resetsettings to no avail.

Any ideas?

EDIT - More detail:

When typing "::", the caret will jump to the beginning of the line, or somewhere in the middle of the first symbol on that line.

When completing a pair of "<>", if there are any nested occurrences thereof, the last ">" is deleted or justified. For example:

```
welcome_mat<
    tuba<
        yip<int>,
        orange<float> // <- after typing newline here...
    > // <- this was the original closing ">" for "welcome_mat" (I didn't type a ">" yet)
// ^---- caret is now here
```

I usually close my templates when I type them, but when arranging multiple arguments, I place them vertically and tend to close them after filling them out. This doesn't happen on single lines.

Comment: Do you have any extensions or add-ons installed?  If so, try disabling these and see if the behavior is associated with one of them.

Comment: Nope, just tried a vanilla reinstall (no SP1), and it started doing it again within a few minutes.

Comment: I think you'll need to give some specific examples.  Given the fact it's happening on scoping operators, it certainly sounds tied to IntelliSense settings, so you might poke around those in Tools/Options/.../C++ etc.

Comment: Turned off intellisense, yet it still jumps around. Added more detail about the behavior to the post.

Comment: Probably better to post an screenshot that shows where the caret appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reinstall it , if that doesn't work look at your keyboard shortcuts maybe you have some wierd shortcuts binds that make the caret move.